# Efficient way to calculate value mathematical functions on DB data

Tags: .net, mysql, sql-server-2008

In .net application, either window or web application,

To perform different mathematical functions like sqrt, maximum,minimum,avg,count on larger amount of data. 
Using stored procedures or normal program logic using iteration. which is the best way for doing this?

Comment: Do you really need a solution for both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: yes i need for the both databases.

Answer (score 4):

Queries or stored procedures are generally faster on larger sets of data. SQL Server is optimized for working with sets, so long as you stay within the set logic (SELECT, GROUP BY,  etc).

If you have a stored procedure with a loop in it, this is a different story, and it won't be a lot more efficient. 
Also, in SQL you will probably have cleaner/less code doing aggregations on data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.For unavailable built-in aggregate functions i have to use either stored procedure or program logic

Comment: @Suresh You can create your own aggregate function for SQL Server in .NET if you find that the manual aggregate calculation is too slow. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot .Whether it is also possible in Mysql Database

Comment: For MySQL you need to program it in C it seems: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answers and time

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is by using `stored procedure`. Anyway all will go just fine as long as your tables are properly indexed. Another reason why I recommend that is because your code is *encapsulated* in the server.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.